# Add user to Server Role in a transaction

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, stored-procedures, transaction

**Situation**

One webapp responsible for creating other webapps using SQL Server 2008 R2 Stored Procedures. One of the steps in creating another webapp is creating a new database, a login/user, assigning database roles, etc.

Now that we are implementing another feature, we would like to assign each new user the pre-defined server role `bulkadmin`. For this, there exists a wonderful SP `sp_addsrvrolemember`.

When executing this, though, we get the error

`The procedure 'sys.sp_addsrvrolemember' cannot be executed within a transaction.`

The webapp that creates the other webapps uses transactions for each SQL query it executes and it would involve a lot of customizations and exceptions to handle this.

**Question**

Is it in another way (or in this way, with some modifications) possible to achieve this, i.e. granting a user the bulkadmin right?

The `sp_addsrvrolemember` has hard-coded that `@@trancount` should be 0, so that's not going to give me a solution. Google and SO have not been really helpful either, or I haven't been able to find it. Usually the answer is "don't use transactions", which is not an option in our case.

Comment: Upgrade to 2012 and use [`ALTER SERVER ROLE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee677634.aspx).

Comment: Didn't know it became that easy in 2012! It's not a direct option to upgrade now, but it's good to consider in the future, thanks. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, just after posting, I found it myself:

```
USE [master];
GRANT ADMINISTER BULK OPERATIONS TO [user]
```

It's that easy.